# celery daemon: not found/celeryd error in configuration file

Tags: ubuntu, celery, celeryd

I was demonizing celery on Ubuntu by following [the user guide](http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html) and [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880360/daemonizing-celery). Briefly,

Download the init-script [celeryd](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/celery/celery/3.1/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd) from celery github repo.

Save the configuration file from [the user guide](http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html) as celeryd.conf (to be distinguished form the init-script `celeryd` above) and edit the settings.

I have an extra step of transferring the above two files from a Windows machine to Ubuntu.

Then

```
sudo cp celeryd /etc/init.d/celeryd
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/celeryd
sudo cp celeryd.conf /etc/default/celeryd
sudo useradd -N -M --system -s /bin/bash celery
sudo addgroup celery
sudo adduser celery celery
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/celery
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/celery
sudo chown -R celery:celery /var/run/celery
sudo chown -R celery:celery /var/log/celery
```

However, when running

```
sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start
```

It throws the error:

```
not found/celeryd: 9: /etc/default/celeryd:
```

The number `9` is the first non-comment line in the configuration file `/etc/default/celeryd`.

What is going on? How should I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the `celeryd` configuration file was edited on Windows and transferred to Ubuntu, therefore, it has '\r\n' as the line ending.

The error message

```
not found/celeryd: 9: /etc/default/celeryd:
```

was not informative. But searching it landed me on [a post](http://djbook.ru/forum/topic/2203/) that pointed me to the right direction. Removing `'\r'` from the configuration file `/etc/default/celeryd` fixes the problem.

So:

```
cp /etc/default/celeryd celeryd
cat celeryd | tr -d '\r' > celeryd
sudo cp celeryd /etc/default/celeryd
```