# deamon celery fails to start "module blah was not found" or "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Tags: python, flask, celery, daemon, systemd

I have setup flask with apache (wsgi) under a venv running python 3.6 on ubuntu 18.04 lts and imported other modules with success. Including celery with rabbitmq.

I followed this guidance for Celery and Flask https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/celery/ and am semi confident celery is called by flask. Because when I run 
    `celery worker -A views.celery` 
it successfully runs and I can see the workers collecting the tasks from what I guess is the rabbitmq queue. (I'm still getting my head around all this).

When I follow the numerous guides online to use systemd or init.d or even the older supervisord I come in to the same problem, which mirrors this [Python - Module Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233140/python-module-not-found) but I have followed it without success.

So to confirm, my error is
    `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`
and the line in question was from 
    `views.celery`
with line
    `from .static.py.forms import blah`
where **static** is the usual flask directory, and **py** is a directory where I store a **forms. py** file.

So because this is using relative importing (So I'm to believe because of the period . ) I remove the period. Flask continues to work. But the new error I receive is 
    `module static.py was not found`

Following the guidance from the other stackoverflow question, I added a 
    `Environment=PATH="/var/www/Flask/app/"`
in the Unit celeryd file. I also have since added blank **__init__. py** files in the directories **static** and **py**.

Appreciate any assistance!!

I have also used these resources but suspect due to my lack of knowledge I have made an error somewhere.

```
https://medium.com/@MicroPyramid/celery-with-supervisor-12522ec397ed
https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/3.1/extra/supervisord/celeryd.conf
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/4.4.2/userguide/daemonizing.html#daemon-systemd-generic
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880360/daemonizing-celery
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-create-user-account/
https://www.maketecheasier.com/add-remove-user-to-groups-in-ubuntu/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3
https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent
```

Comment: I always solve this "problem" by exporting PYTHONPATH to the correct value (the top level directory path of your project).

Answer (score 0):

fixed. It was because I had a folder named 'py'

-_- so annoying